# scrapy command line in Azure Function App

Tags: python, azure, scrapy, azure-functions

**I cannot get the following to work in a Python Function App (Azure):**

```
subprocess.run(["scrapy"])
```

**Why do I need this to work?** I am using advertools (which runs that command, see https://github.com/eliasdabbas/advertools/blob/master/advertools/spider.py)

**What are the issues:**

1. First when deploying, the command line does not add the scrapy command line executable to the path
2. Deploying with oryx, the is an additional issue which oryx ads the wrong python interpreter to the scrapy executable (`#!/tmp/orxy/.../python3`)

**What do I do try to fix this:**

1. add the scrapy exec to my project: `lib/advertools/scrapy_path/scrapy` (with the correct path the python)
2. add that file to my path:

```
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + str(scrapy_bin_path)
```

**What is the result:**

1. running `subprocess.run(["ls", '-la', str(scrapy_bin_path)], capture_output=True, text=True)` returns:

`CompletedProcess(args=['ls', '-la', '/home/site/wwwroot/lib/advertools/scrapy_path'], returncode=0, stdout='total 0\n-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 230 Dec 2 10:10 scrapy\n', stderr='')`

so file is present and executable

2. running `subprocess.run(["which", "scrapy"], capture_output=True, text=True)` returns:

`CompletedProcess(args=['which', 'scrapy'], returncode=0, stdout='/home/site/wwwroot/lib/advertools/scrapy_path/scrapy\n', stderr='')`

encouraging...

3. but now finally running `subprocess.run(["scrapy"], capture_output=True, text=True)` returns:

```
[Information]   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/lib/advertools/test.py", line 74, in exec
    result_scrapy = subprocess.run(["scrapy"], capture_output=True, text=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 505, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1821, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'scrapy'
```

file not found?!

I don't understand why it cannot find 'scrapy' if `which scrapy` does find it